# How to handle calls to multiple functions in the same web service?

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, coldfusion

This is a super newbie question on Flex.  While I am a seasoned programmer, this is my first ever Flex application; please bear with me for my Flex codes.

I have a web service written in ColdFusion.  In this web service, there are two functions; one is to return all the questions in a quiz and the other one is to return all the answer selections to the questions in a quiz.

```
            [Bindable]
        private var questionArray:ArrayCollection;
        private var cfquiz:RemoteObject;

        private function loadQuestions():void {
            currentQuestionCounter = 0;
            btnPrev.enabled = false;
            btnNext.enabled = false;
            cfquiz = new RemoteObject("ColdFusion");
            cfquiz.source = "CFCertExam.cfquiz";
            cfquiz.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHandler);
        }

        private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void {
            questionArray = event.result as ArrayCollection;

            txt1Questions.htmlText = questionArray.getItemAt(currentQuestionCounter).Question_Text;
            btnNext.enabled = true;
        }
```

I have the codes above.  loadQuestions is called at creationComplete to retrieve the questions.  Things are working fine.  What I want to do is to call another function within the same web service, returnAnswers, to return the answer options for a question.  Since I have cfquiz associated to the web service already, I was using cfquiz to call returnAnswers.  However, there is an event listener associated to cfquiz already, resultHandler is being called when returnAnswers comes back with the results.

My questions are, first, is it possible to check which function returns the results within resultHandler?  If so, how?  And second, what is the best way to handle calls to multiple functions within the same web service?

Thanks in advance,
Monte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to specify a handler function for each method which in turn calls a different webservice.

Comment: Please bear with me for a second.  How do you specify a handler function for each method?

Comment: Kobby, thank you very much for your help.  I modified my web service call to use <s:WebService> instead and specified the result handler for each function.  Things are working the way I want now.

Answer (score 1):

The better way to do this is using AsyncToken and AsyncResponder instead of addEventListener,  as following code.

```
tokenA = cfquiz.methodA();
tokenA.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(onResultForMethodA, onFaultMethodA));

tokenB = cfquiz.methodA();
tokenB.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(onResultForMethodB, onFaultMethodB));

tokenC = cfquiz.methodA();
tokenC.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(onResultForMethodC, onFaultMethodC));
```

or

```
tokenA = cfquiz.methodA();
var responderA:IResponder = new AsyncResponder(onResult, onFault, "methodA");
tokenB = cfquiz.methodB();
var responderB:IResponder = new AsyncResponder(onResult, onFault, "methodB");

tokenA.addResponder(responderA);
tokenB.addResponder(responderB);


private function onResult(evt:ResultEvent, token:Object):void {
   if(token == "methodA" ) {
     //logic for methodA
   }
   if(token == "methodB" ) {
     //logic for methodB
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as I can't see where you are calling the actual web service function, for example [from these examples](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_4.html), I am expecting to see:

```
cfquiz = new RemoteObject("ColdFusion");
cfquiz.source = "CFCertExam.cfquiz";
cfquiz.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHandler);
cfquiz.myCFCFunctionCall(); /* where is this? */
```

Anyway, AFAIK you can create a new instance of the remote object and set that up to have it's own event listener.

Hope that helps.

Comment: private function buttonEventHandler():void {
 cfquiz.returnQuestions();
 btnStartExam.enabled = false;
}

Comment: Sorry, as I am only supposed to enter comments, the formatting of the codes is a bit off.  I have a button which would call buttonEventHandler upon clicking.  Sorry, my application is a bit long; that's why I didn't paste all the codes in my original question.

Comment: I had thought about making another instance of the remote object too.  However, wouldn't it save some resources by utilizing the same instance?  Let's say if I were to have ten functions within the web service and I have to make a new instance for EVERY one of those function calls, wouldn't it be a bit redundant and suck up unnecessary resources?  I am asking as a newbie flex programmer; I am not trying to argue with anyone.  I simply want to know what the best practise is.

Comment: In terms of resources you might have a point, but you might not have a choice as there doesn't seem to be a way to do what you are looking for. However - someone more experience with Flex might chime in! In the meantime, since you only have two functions in your web service I'd just create another instance.